# Unwanted background after repositioned span in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I want to move a span from one div to another. 
My solution works ok in Chrome and Safari but Firefox gives me a problem - when the span is moved it has an unwanted background. The background disappears as soon as I click elsewhere on the page but I need to find a way for it not to appear in the first place. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
var clckdEl = null;
var clicked = function(evt) {
  var span = null;
  if (clckdEl) {
    if (clckdEl !== this) {
      span = clckdEl.children[0];
      clckdEl.removeChild(span);
      this.appendChild(span);
    }
    clckdEl.classList.remove('selected');
    clckdEl = null;
  } else if (this.children.length) {
    clckdEl = this;
    clckdEl.classList.add('selected')
  }
};
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('rect'),
  el,
  idx = 0;

for (idx = 0; idx < els.length; idx += 1) {
  el = els[idx];
  el.onclick = clicked;
}
```

```css
.holder {
  font: 100px Arial Unicode MS, sans-serif;
  width: 2em;
  height: 1em;
}

.rect {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  align-items: center;
}

.rect-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.rect-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.letter {
  line-height: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 15%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='holder'>
  <div class='rect rect-blue'>
  </div>
  <div class='rect rect-yellow'>
    <span class='letter'>X</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to disable user-select parameter. 
Simply add this style to your **holder** class:

```
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snyxqkq8/2/)

Comment: Thanks much @KatieIsakadze - that works just fine! And thanks to anyone else who took a look too.